# jQuery: Search text in string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try this:

```
form['comment'] = '<blockquote>test</blockquote><a href="#">test</a> <Your reply here>';

if($(form['comment']).search('<Your reply here>'))
    alert(1)
else
    alert(0)
```

But have this error:

> TypeError: $(form.comment).search is not a function

I fix this problem that:

```
if(form['comment'].value.search('<Вашият отговор тук>') != -1)
    alert(1)
else
    alert(0)
```

Comment: Did you include the jquery js file?

Comment: Yes, I include jquery.js file

Comment: `search` is the method of String, not jQuery object.

Comment: …and it does search for regular expressions, not for substrings

Comment: Rather than edit the title with `[RESOLVED]` or similar, mark the correct answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark beside it.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is `$(form['comment']).text().search()`

So:

```
form = [];
form['comment'] = '<blockquote>test</blockquote><a href="#">test</a> <Your reply here>';

if(form['comment'].search('<Your reply here>') != -1)
    alert(1)
else
    alert(0)​
```

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/hfDWr/).

Comment: It will always alert 1 because in that example, there is always "<Your reply here>" in the text.

Comment: But when I remove <Your reply here> form text again alert 1 :)

Comment: How to get start and end index of search results?

Answer (score 0):

To find out that is matching string to other you don't need jQuery!.

```
var comment = "<blockquote>test</blockquote><a href="#">test</a> <Your reply here>",
    search = "<Your reply here>";


comment.indexOf( search ) != -1;  //  indexOf returns -1 when search does not match
/<Your reply here>/.test( comment ); // returns true when search is in comment.
```